# Update angular component after store updates

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I am implementing NGRX/Redux for the first time and I am not sure why my component doesn't update after adding 1 item to an array in the store.

I have these properties inside my main component:

```
productLines$: Observable<ProductionLine[]>;
productLinesSubscription: Subscription;
productLines: ProductLine[] = [];
```

This is what I do OnInit:

```
this.productLines$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(factorySelectors.factoryFeatureSelector),
      map((store) => store.productionLines)
    );

    this.productLinesSubscription = this.productLines$.subscribe(
      (prodLines) => {
        this.productLines = prodLines.map(
          (productionLine) => new ProductLine(productionLine)
        );
      }
    );
```

I take the objects from the store and, inside the subscription, I map them to a new array.

When I add a new ProductionLine to the database, this effect gets triggered:

```
  createProductionLine$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(factoryActionTypes.createProductionLine),
      concatMap((action) =>
        this.productionLineService.createProductionLine(
          action.productionLineCreateModel
        )
      ),
      mergeMap((productionLine) => [
        factoryActionTypes.productionLineCreated({ productionLine }),
        factoryActionTypes.saveNewProductionLineId({
          newProductionLineId: productionLine.productionLineId
        })
      ])
    )
  );
```

And finally the reducer changes the store:

```
  on(factoryActionTypes.productionLineCreated, (state, action) => ({
    ...state,
    productionLines: [...state.productionLines, action.productionLine]
  })),
```

This is the HTML.As you can see I am not using Observable<ProductionLine[]> for the forLoop but the Array I create inside the subscription:

```
<div class="product-line-group-container">
        <div
          *ngFor="let productLine of productLines"
          class="product-line-container"
        >
          <sm-line-overview
            [productLine]="productLine"
            (deleteClicked)="deleteProductLine($event)"
            (editClicked)="editProductLine($event)"
          >
          </sm-line-overview>
        </div>
      </div>
```

.

When I look at my Store, I see the new Object inside the array but the component itself doesn't add the new ProductionLine on the page. Am I missing something?
It may be a basic thing but I am quite new to this.
If more code is needed let me know.
Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: Do you have the change detection on your component set to OnPush??

Comment: I tried OnPush before and didn't work. 
After reading your comment I decided to try the other options and well, Default works. I didn't expect it to work to be honest and feel dumb for not trying it before asking. 
I saw OnPush and thought that was the one I needed but it seems Default was the one needed(?). Shouldn't Default be active without writing it?

Comment: oh sorry, I wasnt suggesting OnPush as a solution..Usually when your template doesnt update, it because the binding was updated after change detection ran. This is usually the case with OnPush change detection where change detection only runs when input bindings change or a user event (like click) occurs. 
You shouldnt have to specify the change detection to be default. On Push change detection cascades to the children of the component on which it is declared. Do one of the parent components have OnPush on them?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `private cd: ChangeDetectorRef` and `cd.detectChanges()` into subscribe should help.

Comment: This may be useful in the future. It seems it was way easier than I thought. (see my other answer). Thanks for the suggestion!